# React click handler passed to child component is not working

Tags: reactjs

I've tried to pass click handler to SignIn component, but it doesn't work for me. I get log and then page refreshes

`Auth` class:

```
class Auth extends Component {

login() {
    console.log('Clicked'); //only this method works
    fetch('/api/auth/signin', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf8'
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            this.props.history.push('/api/categories')
        }
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <SignIn onCustomClick={this.login}/> //onClick handler
    )
}
```

SignIn component

```
export default function SignIn(props) {
    const {onCustomClick} = props; // props
      return (
              <Button
                type="submit"
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                className={classes.submit}
                onClick={onCustomClick} // onClick handler
              >)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **bind your login function to the class context**. Write it as an `arrow function` to achieve that.

Also add `e.preventDefault` to prevent the default browser behaviour on form submit to refresh the page with submitted information

```
class Auth extends Component {

    login = (e) =>  { // Arrow function here
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default browser behaviour to refresh
        fetch('/api/auth/signin', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf8'
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                this.props.history.push('/api/categories')
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SignIn onCustomClick={this.login}/> //onClick handler
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Still refreshes after console output. Please check update

Comment: Are you getting redirected to `/api/categories` page?

Comment: You need to add `e.preventDefault()` to prevent page refresh on submit

Comment: @NurulSundarani i get redirect to ```/api/auth?email=email&password=password```

Comment: @Vadim Try e.preventDefault()

Comment: Yes, as @ShubhamKhatri mentioned, can you try
```login = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
// Your rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your login function is not binded, you can use arrow functions or explicitly bind it in the constructor for it to work.

```
class Auth extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  // here your function is binded
  this.login = this.login.bind(this);
}

login() {
    console.log('Clicked'); //only this method works
    fetch('/api/auth/signin', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf8'
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            this.props.history.push('/api/categories')
        }
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <SignIn onCustomClick={this.login}/> //onClick handler
    )
}
```