# Passing a React click handler to child components

Tags: reactjs

My `SquareClicker` component renders a `SquareGrid`, which in turn contains clickable `Square`s:

```
class SquareClicker extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      grid: Array.from(Array(5).keys()).map(
        i => Array.from(Array(5).keys()).map(
          j => <Square key={((i*5)+j).toString()} onClick={this.handleClick}/>
        )
      )  
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    console.log("A square has been clicked.");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="square-clicker">
        <SquareGrid grid={this.state.grid}/>
      </div>
      );
  };
}

class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={"square"} />
    );
  };
}
```

When I click on squares, nothing is logged to the console.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790953/react-click-handler-passed-to-child-component-is-not-working) is similar - but as you can see, I have bound the `handleClick` function to the component context with `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);`.

How do I make my squares clickable?

Comment: Can you provide the code for your `Square ` class ?

Comment: @Frosty619 Sure, I've updated my code.

Comment: Storing react elements inside of component state is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @trixn Thanks.  How do I avoid this anti-pattern?

Comment: @alex, You're not attaching the clickHandler in your `Square` Component!

Comment: Your state should only contain plain data and the render function of `SquareGrid` should take care of rendering the `<Square>`s given the plain data.

Comment: @alex You need to pass function handler as prop to child component where you have actually click happening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Pass function to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407785/react-pass-function-to-child-component)

Comment: @trixn Just as a heads-up, I fixed this "anti-pattern", but this approach has its own problems.  In reality, my program has many layers of abstraction via parent/child component relationships, so in order to fix this anti-pattern, I had to decorate like five components with `squareClicker={this.props.squareClicker}`.  It feels messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misread your post initially, sorry (I got `<Square>` and `<SquareGrid>` mixed up), try this in setting your `<Square>` component...

```
j => <Square key={((i*5)+j).toString()} click={this.handleClick}/>
```

Then in your `<Square>` component, set `render()` as so...

```
render() {
    return (
        <div
            className={"square"}
            onClick={(e) => this.props.click(e)}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: What's `this.props.click`?

Comment: @alex: Those are the props for the sub-class.  You would have this accessible if you had a constructor in your `class Square extends React.Component`.  It's typical to have constructors in components.  You need to be able to pass `props` (properties) to child components.

Comment: Ah ok, I missed `click={this.handleClick}`.  Thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: This worked, thanks.  Do you know how I would pass parameters to the `handleClick` function?  For instance, the coordinates of the square I clicked (for example given `this.props.rowNumber` and `this.props.colNumber`)?

Comment: Hey, alex: Thanks for accepting!  Yes, I do indeed know how to pass parms like that -- change above to `onClick={(e, parm1) => this.props.click(e, parm1)}`, and then change `handleClick(e)` to `handleClick(e, parm1)`, actually I forgot to include the `(e)` args in the answer above, so, added that just now!  Thanks for noticing, hope this helps.

Comment: Works like a charm - thanks a million!  Pretty unfortunate that this sort of thing seems to  *absolutely require* an ES6 arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass click event to `SquareGrid`

```js
// In SquareClicker

 <SquareGrid grid={this.state.grid} click={this.handleClick} />
```

and inside `SquareGrid` component, you will use `click` prop like below:

```js
class SquareGrid extends React.Component {
 ...

return (
// ...you code
 <Square click={this.props.click} />
)

}
```

and then inside `Square` component pass this prop again

```js
class Square extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={"square"} onClick={this.props.click}/>
    );
  };
}
```